# Storing 4 int32 values inside each PB message as 4 different variables 'instead of using repeated' to avoid parsing back as ''List of Integers''

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

For my usecase of Protocol Buffers, I need to serialize 4 integers(at max.) inside each protocol buffer message. I want that when I retrieve those 4 integers from message, I get them as `int`and not as `Integer`. (The reason for this being I need some really fast calculations and equality checking(with some other int) on those retrieved integers)

If I use the `repeated` type in the PB message, then on parsing from the bytes, I get the `list` of `Integer`. Thus I planning to use **4 different variable**(each `int32` with `optional` tag) inside each PB message **instead of using `repeated`**. Thus I expect to get the integers as `int` and not as `Integers`

Is this a good idea & Will this help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will certainly avoid the "list" issue. In regular .proto the size will be the same as long as the field numbers are small - the only difference on the wire will be *different* field numbers instead of the same number 4 times. However, if your list is currently using the "packed" option it will be *marginally* larger as 4 fields.

Personally, since the size is capped at 4, I think the 4 field approach represents your scenario more closely, as otherwise there is nothing to stop you adding 20 values. I'm all for the 4 field approach here.